# Redis: storing key/value pair without expiration time

Tags: java, spring, caching, redis, spring-data-redis

Can someone explain me how to store key/value pair in redis with unlimited exipire time?

I was trying to find some information at stackoverflow and google and I found nothing.

I'm using redisTemplate and I see there is only `expire` method there with timeout to specify. I can eventually set the timeout to value like 999999999 days, but I think thats not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

By default, no expiry is set on the keys. That is, if you do not specify an expiry yourself, your key will be stored indefinetely without any expiry.

```
set myname Ankit
OK

ttl myname
(integer) -1
```

A return of `-1` tell us that there is no expiry set on the key `myname`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found two answers to this question - at first I can use expire method with -1 value as a timeout:

```
redisTemplate.expire("mykey", -1);
```

and the second way is to use persist method on key:

```
redisTemplate.persist("mykey");
```

This will remove the expiry time for the "mykey" key, effectively setting it to never expire.